# Too big of a damage difference?

Tags: borderlands-2

I play an SMG Siren. I have a few skills:

- 7/5 Accelerate which gives me 21% more gun damage
- 5/5 Reaper which gives me 40% more gun damage on enemy's health above 50%
- Cat Mod which gives me 71% more SMG damage.

I have two SMGs:

[image] and [image]

The damage difference between both is nullable, as the other bonuses. The only difference is the element. Even though, I hit around 4-5k with the Slag one, and around 2-2.5k with the Shock one. These damages are done on Normal playthrough on Flesh enemies.

Seen this [table of element](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Elemental_Damage#Elemental_effectiveness), both Shock and Slag deal 1 on Flesh.

I don't have any boost to Slag damage, nor Tediore weapons. Am I missing something?

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Arqade! Where are you getting these numbers from? Are you testing your damage on the target practice dummy in Marcus' shop in Sanctuary?

Comment: No on real enemies. But I think I've found out what happened. The two bullets of the Shock one sometimes split, so I hit an enemy with only one bullet, halving the damage.

Comment: It's good to always test on the training dummy. That way you have a static point to go from, otherwise we'd need to know the level of the enemy you killed with the two guns (perhaps they were two different levelled enemies, so different damage), the type of enemy, etc.

Comment: What are the enemies? Robot-kind enemies will be affected by slag like crazy, but creature-ish ones will get nearly the same damage from electrical damage and slag...

Comment: You've mentioned "two bullets of the Shock one". Plasma Casters don't only release one projectile for the cost of two ammunition ,do they not? And even with fire rate of 8 two consequent projectiles always display separate damage numbers.

Comment: I can see the Shock "bullet" (more an "orb") splits after a few meters